# Bing Maps Issue on Safari 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, bing-maps

So i am having an issue in which the bing maps are not rendered completely on Safari 7. They are loaded fine on Chrome and IE.
*Example* - copy and paste the link into Safari 7 on a Mac : 
http://www.levi.com/GB/en_GB/findAStore

As You can see only half the map renders the other half is gray, i get no errors in the console, 
the only warning i get is:
**"Invalid CSS property declaration at:*       style.css"**

Is anyone else running into this issue? is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 3):

Try `text-align:left` in the style of the mapViewer div, it is likely that the map is inheriting the property `text-align: center` and that also applies to images of the map

Answer (score 0):

Sytle.css is a file in your website. Start by looking into that file. Maybe comment out the reference and see if the issue still persists.

Bing maps works fine in Safari 7. The forum post you saw on the Bing Maps forums about Safari 7 ended up being an error in the users code and not with Bing Maps.

In your case you have not specified a css position, width or height property for the map. This is the #1 cause of issues between different browsers. IE and Chrome are fine with this, but other browsers like Safari require these to render correctly.

Comment: As I mentioned, your map has no CSS position, width or height value. These are very basic things that are common causes of issues in Safari. Safari is a very picky browser. Also, as you saw in the Bing Maps forums, I recommended that enterprise customers contact the Bing Maps Enterprise support team. Levi would qualify as one of these customers... also, the Bing Maps Enterprise Support team is contracted out by a team at Infusion. you might want to reach out to them internally.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue. `text-align: center` causes it and `text-align: left` fixes it.

rbrundritt, as this problem has come up repeatedly and your answer is always that the issue is style position, width, or height, you should know that the issue is that the div's `text-align` style impacts the rendering of the maps on Safari and iOS in Bing 7 and that setting to `text-align: left` will fix it.