# Bing map bug on Safari 7 (or Safari bug?)

Tags: safari, bing-maps, bing

I am displaying a set of properties on Bing map. It works all fine in Chrome, FireFox, IE, and Safari on Windows (version is 5.1.7 - their latest version for Windows). But it doesn't work in Safari 7 on Mac.

When displayed correctly, all properties are located on a green residential area. But on Safari 7, all properties are displayed on the far left of that area - on a totally wrong location. Also, the larger left part of the map is blank (there is no map!).

I saw a similar post [Bing Maps Issue on Safari 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165387/bing-maps-issue-on-safari-7). The left part of their map is also blank. The problem there seems not solved. I followed Microsoft's guideline (meta, CSS position/width/height etc), none of them work.

I suspect that's a Bing bug? Or a Safari bug?

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I solve the problem, I confirm that this is NOT a bug of Safari or Bing.

the `<div>` that load the the map is embedded in many other `div`s, `panel`s, `fieldset`, `Telerik ajax panel`, `RadTabStrip` etc. You have to remove some of `div`s, and also some styles of `div`s to make it work. It's tricky, you have to do many tests to finally pin down which element caused the problem and remove that element.

I took me several days to figure this out.